# React/Next.js how to get other Element event target value on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, next.js

I have an input element and a button in React:

```
      <li><input type="text" placeholder="Enter new ID"></input>
      <button onClick={(e)=>this.saveKonfigElementHandler()}>Save</button></li>
```

Now, when I enter some value into the input field, I want to save the value into some array when I click on the button. 
Is it somehow possible to get a reference to that input field (e.g. the target.value of the input field) to save it when clicking the button?

Or would I simply have to do it with an onChange event that saves the current input value into some Variable, and when I click the button, I will simply retrieve that value to save it into some array? Maybe that would be a lot simpler.

E.g:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.inputFieldText.join('')} onChange={(event) => this.textHandler(event)}></input>
```

in the textHandler Method, I will save the target value from the input field into a Class Component state variable in the textHandler() method. And when I click the button, I retrieve that state value and can do some manipulation with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to get a reference to that input field (e.g. the target.value of the input field) to save it when clicking the button?

Yes.

> Or would I simply have to do it with an onChange event that saves the current input value into some Variable, and when I click the button, I will simply retrieve that value to save it into some array? Maybe that would be a lot simpler.

That would be a slightly more React way to do it.

Your DOM-only approach is more "uncontrolled" (see [these docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for what controlled/uncontrolled means). You'd do it like this:

1. Change your `onClick` to pass `e` to the handler:

   ```
   onClick={(e)=>this.saveKonfigElementHandler(e)}
   ```
2. In `saveKonfigElementHandler`, use `e.target.previousElementSibling` to access the `input`:

   ```
   saveKonfigElementHandler(e) {
       const { value } = e.target.previousElementSibling;
       // Use `value` ...
   }
   ```

That's fragile, of course; if you change your structure so another element is between the `button` and the `input`, or the `input` is within a container element, etc., it'll break — which is one argument for the controlled approach. You could store a link to the `input` in a data attribute on the `button`:

```
<li><input id="id-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter new ID"/>
<button data-input="#id-input" onClick={(e)=>this.saveKonfigElementHandler(e)}>Save</button></li>
```

and then use `querySelector` to get it:

```
saveKonfigElementHandler(e) {
    const { value } = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("data-input"));
    // Use `value` ...
}
```

but the you're having to keep selectors unique, etc.

Which you choose, controlled or uncontrolled, is ultimately up to you.

Comment: thanks, I tried all 3 possibilities, all of them work.

Answer (score 9):

[A modern way to do it](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-started-with-react-hooks-controlled-forms-826c99943b92), with function components, hooks and a controlled form element, is:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function MyComponent({ initialId, onSave }) {
  const [newId, setNewId] = useState(initialId)

  return (
    <li>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Enter new ID" 
        onChange={(e) => setNewId(e.target.value)} 
      />
      <button onClick={() => onSave(newId)}>Save</button>
    </li>
  )
}
```

I'd also note that [it is considered better accessibility practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Labels_and_placeholders) to use a `label` element for describing the purpose of your field, rather than a placeholder. Placeholders are more appropriate for example input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question. Do you want something like this ?

```
<button data-input="#id-input" onClick={this.saveKonfigElementHandler(value)}>Save</button></li>

saveKonfigElementHandler = (value) => (event) => {}
```